# If there a way to deploy with git without copying the whole meta data (history of changed)?

Tags: git, deployment

Dev environment: Linux

If there a way to deploy with git without copying the whole meta data (history of changed)?

I want to be able to push a certain branch, but I don't care much about pushing the history of changes ... if that possible with GIT?

Comment: maybe look at `git rebase`?

Comment: yeah and there is also a way to branch with --orphan option ... thx for the rebase hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout a new branch and make a new commit with the current state:

```
git checkout -b temp
git update-ref -d refs/heads/temp
git commit -m "Fresh commit"
```

Push the temp branch now!

Or try `git checkout --orphan temp` to create an orphan branch that behaves the same.

Rebase using `git rebase --root -i`, but that will be a tedious process.

Comment: look like you can also do a `git clone --depth ...`

Answer (score 0):

The entire git history is stored within the .git directory off the root of your project. If you remove that directory on the deployment server, what's left is just the current code. It's not even technically a git project at that point.

Details here: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html

You're not technically "deploying" just the current code, but the end result is the same.

Hope that's useful.